# Keep carriage returns in text from <pre> after parsing

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I am using the Simple html dom (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) library for this function.

I would like to parse the contents of the pre tag of a website, for which I am using this code:

```
    <?php include '/libraries/simple_html_dom.php' ?>
    <?php
    // Create DOM from URL or file
    $html = file_get_html('testing.html');

     // Find the Text
    foreach($html->find('pre') as $element) 
           echo '<p>' . $element . '<p>';      
    ?>
```

This is the contents of the file 'testing.html':

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <pre>
    am.o                 V      1 1 PRES ACTIVE  IND 1 S    
    amo, amare, amavi, amatus  V   [XXXAO]  
    love, like; fall in love with; be fond of; have a tendency to;
    am.as                N      1 1 ACC P F                 
    ama, amae  N  F   [XXXDO]    lesser
    bucket; water bucket; (esp. fireman's bucket);
    am.as                V      1 1 PRES ACTIVE  IND 2 S    
    amo, amare, amavi, amatus  V   [XXXAO]  
    love, like; fall in love with; be fond of; have a tendency to;
    </pre>
    </body>
    </html>
```

As you can see the pre text has carridge returns, which I want to preserve in the output. At the moment this is the output of the parser:

```
  am.o                 V      1 1 PRES ACTIVE  IND 1 S      amo, amare, amavi, amatus  V   [XXXAO]    love, like; fall in love with; be fond of; have a tendency to;  am.as                N      1 1 ACC P F                   ama, amae  N  F   [XXXDO]    lesser  bucket; water bucket; (esp. fireman's bucket);  am.as                V      1 1 PRES ACTIVE  IND 2 S      amo, amare, amavi, amatus  V   [XXXAO]    love, like; fall in love with; be fond of; have a tendency to;
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Try [`nl2br()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: You can't expect to preserve whitespace with simple html dom. Use preg functions if you need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was quite simple really! Simple HTML Dom was not required as it can be done without a library like this:

```
$file = file_get_contents('testing.html');
$start = '<html>';
$end   = '<pre>';
$string = $file;
$whatwearelookingfor = strstr( substr( $string, strpos( $string, $start) + strlen( $start)), $end, true);
$parsedresult = str_replace($whatwearelookingfor,"",$file);
$parsedresult = str_replace("<html>","",$parsedresult);
$parsedresult = str_replace("</body></html>","",$parsedresult);
echo $parsedresult;
```

It returns the contents of the pre - Preserving returns!

Answer (score 1):

use `echo '<p>' . $element->innerHTML . '<p>';`

Answer (score 1):

Replace the newline characters with a BR tag.  You can use [nl2br()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.nl2br.php) for this.

Comment: Is there an easy way to implement this?

Comment: Yes, `echo '<p>' . nl2br($element) . '<p>';`

Comment: Try `echo '<p>' . str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), '<br />', $element) . '<p>';`

Comment: Sorry - No luck! @LukePeterson

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the text node:

```
foreach($html->find('pre') as $element) 
           echo '<p>' . $element->innertext . '<p>';
```

Comment: @JBithell can you try to `print_r($element);`

Comment: Output was over 30,000 chars of this: ivate] => simple_html_dom Object *RECURSION* ) ) [parent] => [_] => Array ( [0] => -1 [1] => 12 ) [tag_start] => 0 [dom:simple_html_dom_node:private] => simple_html_dom Object *RECURSION* ) [1] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 1 [tag] => html [attr] => Array ( ) [children] => Array ( [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 1 [tag] => he

Comment: @JBithell were u able to find the target text somewehere in the output ?

Comment: Yes - But still in one line @Amir

Comment: @JBithell what do you mean by one line

Comment: There are no cartridge reruns @Amir